# Sinatra always prints '!! Invalid request" on standard output

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was messing around and recklessly trying to implement SSL with Sinatra. I was using many scripts that I found on the internet without actually knowing what they did. I then realized I didn't actually need SSL and now sinatra is completely broken.

No matter what my app is, it always always prints "!! Invalid request" on the terminal whenever it receives a request from the browser. I've noticed that the `http://localhost:4567` always switches to `https://localhost:4567` in the browser URL.

I would like to have Sinatra act like it did when I originally installed it.

I'm new to this...

Comment: Uninstall & reinstall `Sinatra`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried doing that and it kept the configuration settings even after I re-installed it. Somehow a script that I ran using sinatra completely reconfigured sinatra itself, and the configuration seems permanent.

Comment: Nothing is permanent. Remove and reinstall Ruby, and all the gems associated. Then do a fresh install of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall & reinstall `Sinatra` and Ruby